# Google analytics credentials at client side

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I am currently new for Google analytics API throu Javascript. I am implementing some of charts and for first load, page is redirecting me to google site to login with Analytics account and then returning to my orignal page, refresh & chart show.

Here, I would like to avoid users to redirect to google analytics page and instead of that I want to stored credentials somewhere in config file or in application variable.

I tried to search and read many blogs & articles however no success.

Is there any trick/ ideas by which I can get any API which could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't allow you to pull the physical charts onto your site, since they are generated on the fly.  What you can do, is grab the data from their API and then display the data as needed on your site.  I have searched and found a few examples with [this](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/03/embed-analytics-using-the-google-analtyics-api/) one looking like it might do the trick.

It goes through the steps of pulling the data through the API, displaying/formatting/styling the data, and adding the chart to the page.  Try that, [Embed Analytics Using the Google Analytics API](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/03/embed-analytics-using-the-google-analtyics-api/).

Comment: Hello, I guess my question was not clear. 
I was able to show charts on my pages, however I would like to avoid user first time to enter credentials on google analytics. 
The link which you provided is of PHP where it been shown that credentials can be stored in file, however I am developing this through javascript and asp.net.

Comment: Here is a blog post for a [Javascript](http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/reporting/javascript/ez-ga-dash/docs/user-documentation.html) library to display charts.  Knowing you already have the charts on the page, this may have the info needed to authenticate the page so new users don't need to log on for every initial load of the data.

Comment: Hi Walls,
I am referring same javascript library for showing charts. I have all API key, client ID and table ID as well. However still each user who is accessing this page is need to get authenticate first.
I am not sure where I can find point you mentioned on that page.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you are redirected to a Google login page, is that Google connects to the analytics data for whichever user you log in as.  This means each user that logs into the site would see their own Analytics info, not the info from a static account.

If you want it to be the same user's analytics data no matter who is logging in, you would need to setup a "Service Account" on Google's API Console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/), then use those credentials when logging in.

It seems like a lot of people are looking for a solution to this, so I created a nuGet package that:
 - connects to a "Service Account" you set up in the API Console
 - Pulls any Google Analytics data you would like
 - Displays that data using Google's Charts API 
and it does all of this in a very easy to modify way.  You can see more here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAnalytics.GoogleCharts.NET/.